# Value of type 'AVCaptureDevice' has no member 'supporteddepthdataformats'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation

supporteddepthdataformats is listed in Apple documentation 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice.format/2865753-supporteddepthdataformats
but can't be seen from code by:

```
let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)
print("depth data formats: \(device.supportedDepthDataFormats)")
```

Error message said:

```
Value of type 'AVCaptureDevice' has no member 'supporteddepthdataformats'
```

I am using Xcode Version 9.2 beta (9C34b) since the current official Xcode 9.1 does not work with iOS 11.2.

Comment: That's member of `AVCaptureDevice.Format`

Comment: Hah, right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back )
print("depth data formats: \(device?.activeFormat.supportedDepthDataFormats)")
```

Hope this helps